# EOFError when downloading cifar10 dataset

Tags: python-3.x

I am downloading cifar10 dataset in keras as:

```
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
```

The following error is shown

```
Untaring file...
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-996c10ccd1de>", line 1, in <module>
    (X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()

  File "/home/meenu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/datasets/cifar10.py", line 17, in load_data
    path = get_file(dirname, origin=origin, untar=True)

  File "/home/meenu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/data_utils.py", line 129, in get_file
    tfile.extractall(path=datadir)

  File "/home/meenu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/tarfile.py", line 2007, in extractall
    numeric_owner=numeric_owner)

  File "/home/meenu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/tarfile.py", line 2049, in extract
    numeric_owner=numeric_owner)

  File "/home/meenu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/tarfile.py", line 2119, in _extract_member
    self.makefile(tarinfo, targetpath)

  File "/home/meenu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/tarfile.py", line 2168, in makefile
    copyfileobj(source, target, tarinfo.size, ReadError, bufsize)

  File "/home/meenu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/tarfile.py", line 248, in copyfileobj
    buf = src.read(bufsize)

  File "/home/meenu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/gzip.py", line 276, in read
    return self._buffer.read(size)

  File "/home/meenu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/_compression.py", line 68, in readinto
    data = self.read(len(byte_view))

  File "/home/meenu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/gzip.py", line 482, in read
    raise EOFError("Compressed file ended before the "

EOFError: Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached
```

Answer (score 0):

I re-download the cifar-10 datasets, check its md5sum, then fixed